# Error when deploying Xamarin forms app to iphone in Visual studio 2017 for mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

My **VS for mac** version is 7.3.2. 
I have an iOS developer acct and I did the following for deploying xamarin forms app to iPhone.

Problem:  No installed provisioning profiles match the installed ios signing identities

I follow below references:

-1- setup provision profile
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/

-2-install fastlane
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/fastlane/

```
I took these Steps. After installed fastlane: 

1) In Visual Studio for mac for setting up provisioning profile:

Automatically (Recommended) 

I have used the signIn button but I dont see anything. No Apple account shown.

2) I select my iphone in Visual Studio for Mac for deployment. however it showed below error:
Problem:  No installed provisioning profiles match the installed ios signing identities
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using certificate and profile instead of choosing Automatic.
Sometimes if you have installed profiles multiple times its gets improper profile.
Also please verify that you have added the Device UDID in the profile you are using.

Comment: In my mac, I have my ios app which I had deployed to my iphone and Appstore  before installing visual Studio for mac. so when using vs for mac, I need to create app ID and upload CSR one more time? I had done this CSR many times but the App ID is unique ones. So if I do this App ID with wildcard for VS for mac, will it affect my next iOS app development?

Comment: I need to create app ID and upload CSR one more time? No you can use the existing certificate and profiles only. So if I do this App ID with wildcard for VS for mac, will it affect my next iOS app development? No it will affect you next iOS app